# How to get rid of "NOTE" warning?

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I had just installed ruby 1.9.2 via RVM on ubuntu 11.04,
and then sudo install rubygem.

after that, whenever i use gem, i will have the following notice

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /home/shrimpy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /home/shrimpy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /home/shrimpy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
```

They are annoying to me. how can i fix it? or get rid of it?

Comment: Just as a pointer, you don't need to do `sudo install rubygem` with 1.9.2 because 1.9.2 already includes it, and [you shouldn't use `sudo` with any gems under RVM's control](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/).

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
rvm rubygems current
```

Have also heard this works for some:

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

Comment: Not work! showing below error

```ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory```

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the message:

> NOTE:
>   Gem::Specification#**default_executable=
>   is deprecated** with no replacement. It
>   will be removed on or after
>   2011-10-01.
>   Gem::Specification#**default_executable=
>   called from
>   /home/shrimpy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10**.

Some Gem used the depreciated `default_executable` thing, which Ruby dislikes.

Edit that file to fix it, if you dare.